# Adobe XD: Click and drag only selected layer(s)

Tags: adobe-xd

In Sketch I can select multiple layers and then hold down `⌥ + ⌘` (Option + Command on Mac) to move only those selected layers.

This is extremely useful when layers are nested or I have just duplicated a layer and want to move it to a new location.

UPDATE: GIFs to show what I am trying to accomplish:

Desired behavior demoed in Sketch -

[image]

Trying to accomplish in XD -

[image]

Does XD have an equivalent feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on Windows, and I assume <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+click on Mac to select mulitple layers. In XD, there's no need to hold down any keys when you move the objects.

[image]

If you are simply trying to move layers to a different position in the layers panel, Holding down <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> as you click and drag a selection of multiple layers also seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Apologies if my question was unclear. I added a few GIFs showing desired functionality in XD. I am assuming Xd does not have this capability.

Comment: @TylerYoc You could temporarily hide the layer that's above the one you want to move.

Comment: That would work in some situations. I think my best bet is to add this to the user forums. Thank you for your response.